# Why const objects are local to file in c++?

Tags: c++

Consider the following `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` files:

```
ebra@him:/tmp$ cat a.cpp 
const int i = 5;

ebra@him:/tmp$ cat b.cpp 
int main()
{
  extern int i;
  return i;
}

ebra@him:/tmp$ g++ *.cpp
/tmp/ccqBWi4e.o: In function `main':
b.cpp:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `i'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The question is how I can use the `i` variable that is declared in `a.cpp` file inside `b.cpp`?

Note that

1. I added the keyword `const` inside `b.cpp` too, but nothing changed.
2. I have the same problem with `static` and `static const` variables too!

Comment: static are always local to a file. Why did you declare `extern int i` inside `main`? it should have been declared outside.

Comment: @fionbio it is absolutely not necessary to use includes to refer to an entity declared in one source file from another. The issue here is linkage.

Comment: Add this line to the very beginning of a.cpp: `extern const int i;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, when you declare a variable to be `const` at namespace scope it automatically has internal linkage. Adding `static` will also yield in internal linkage with or without `const`

Therefore they are not available outside the translation unit, hence the linker error.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a header file, that way they both have the same value (different variables, same name, same value).

I think you can also override to make it external linkage, but this will get you nothing: no behaviour changes; No efficiency improvement, for int.